# A letra "h" na língua portuguesa

Tags: ortografia, fonemas, fonologia

A letra "h" na língua portuguesa é diferente das demais, pois não corresponde a um fonema. Em certos casos é associada a uma consoante, constituindo um dígrafo.

> Exemplo:
>   trabalho, banho, chapéu.

É também empregada em: ah!, eh!, ih!, oh!, etc.

É correto usar "h" com som de "r"?

> Exemplo:
>   hash, handball, etc.

Quais os problemas em aceitar este tipo de estrangeirismo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essas palavras não estão presentes no idioma português, portanto não podem seguir essas regras.

E, se forem incorporadas, devem seguir a pronúncia original ou alterar a forma da escrita.